# SQLite3 OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

I have looked everywhere and cannot figure out why this is not working.

```
import sqlite3

path = '/Users/...'
con = sqlite3.connect(path+'YSD.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()
cmd = 'SELECT ISD_NAME replace(ISD_NAME,"Statewide"," Statewide") FROM enr'
cur.execute(cmd)
con.commit()
con.close()

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

I have also tried this, to no avail:

```
cmd = 'SELECT ISD_NAME replace(ISD_NAME,?,?) FROM enr'
cur.execute(cmd, ("\"Statewide\"","\" Statewide\""))
```

Comment: `SELECT ... replace` is not a valid SQL query. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to fetch `ISD_NAME` column values and replace **"Statewide"** with **" Statewide"** remove `ISD_NAME` after `SELECT` statement.

For instance, assuming you have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE enr("id" PRIMARY KEY, "ISD_NAME" VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO enr VALUES (1, "somethingStatewide");
```

Your script becomes:

```py
cmd = 'SELECT replace(ISD_NAME,"Statewide"," Statewide") FROM enr'
cur.execute(cmd)
```

Test with print:

```py
records = cur.fetchall()
print(records)
```

Here the result:

```py
[(u'something Statewide',)]
```

Comment: I was actually trying to replace the values in the database. Should have been using: 'UPDATE enr SET ISD_NAME = " Statewide" WHERE ISD_NAME = "Statewide";'